# didFinishLoadForFrame doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I've created a very simple Mac program to load a web page. It works and loads it well but I can't run events! Nothing is logged!

```
#import "BenotaAppDelegate.h"
@implementation BenotaAppDelegate
@synthesize webViewIns;
@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[webViewIns mainFrame] loadRequest:req];
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSLog(@"didFinishLoadForFrame");
}
@end
```

I can not use delegate right....

Comment: Did you set a delegate for the web view?

Comment: No :D I searched about delegating and protocols and will learn about them and then will back to this question. Do you know simple reference about it to start? developer.apple is not friendly for starters...

Comment: Protocol was used but nothing changed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set outlet `frameLoadDelegate`from your webView object to a class, that contains a method `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:`

[image: Connections inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that my (iOS) app was rejected due:

> non-public API/s in your app:
>   webView:didFinishLoadForFrame

You might want to reconsider your app, I definitely must find the 3rd party lib, which called that, and get rid of it. "It wasn't me!" is not a valid excuse :)

Comment: But this is a public API: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: my app was iOS, not OS X! That method doesn't seem to be public in iOS. It was used by a debugging framework, whose release notes especially said the framework must NOT be included in release. Next time I'll read instructions more carefully :)