# when a webpage has really finished rending?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, webkit

I have a WebView and I want to know when the webview has finished rending.I set the WebFrameLoad Delegate and find the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` is called.In this delegate function I code as follow

```
if ([sender mainFrame] == frame) {
    NSLog(@"mainFrame");
}else{
    NSLog(@"frame");
}
```

I hope the "mainFrame" is printed once when the webpage finish rending and In fact this works well in most case. However, some of webpage need to redirect and as a result the "mainFrame" is printed many times. Whether there is a function that will be really called once when the webpage which need to redirect finish rending.

I try the notification named "WebViewProgressFinishedNotification". But the result is same. Any one tell me why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you try this [almost same use case][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118671/didfinishloadforframe-doesnt-work

Comment: It's different.I set the delegate.The webView:didFinishLoadForFrame function works well.Thank u!