# Objective-C on OS X : setting an outlet programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, osx-mavericks

I'm creating an app that is using WebView to load content from the web but the WebView isn't displayed to the user and I want to know when the page has finished loading, to do that, I will be using *didFinishLoadForFrame* but to make this thing work [I saw that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118671/didfinishloadforframe-doesnt-work) :

> You need to set outlet **frameLoadDelegate** from your webView object to a
>   class, that contains a method webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:

My problem is that I don't know how to do that without using Interface Builder... what code should I write and where should I write it ?

Here is the content of AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *myWeb;
@end
```

And here is the content of AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[self.myWeb mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
}


- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSLog(@"La page a été chargée !");
}

@end
```

Thank you

Comment: BTW I'm new to the Objective-C programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an *outlet* as such, it's just a standard Objective-C property:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.myWeb.frameLoadDelegate = self;   
    [[self.myWeb mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
}
```

It's unlikely, however, that this should be in the app delegate, however that's kinda outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Why shouldn't it be in the app delegate ? (I'm new to Objective-C programming !).

I don't know if you can help me or if I should open a new thread, but I have got an other problem with this thing : it looks like nothing is loading if I don't link a UI element to @property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *monWeb;
Do you know why ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yes I do know why, and the other answer (from NeverHopeless) alludes to why that is.  Simply declaring a pointer to an object won't actually create that object; it either needs to serialized from NIB (using Interface Builder) or you need to create it programmatically.  This is a fundamental issue that is outside the scope of your original question, so you should probably spend some time studying this.

Answer (score 1):

For programmatically, you need to initalize your `UIWebView` and its delegates inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
    [self.myWeb =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
     self.myWeb.frameLoadDelegate =s elf; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.myWeb];

#if ARC
    [self.myWeb release];
#endif
```